# How do I change the font of text in pygame

Tags: python, fonts, pygame, raspberry-pi3

I have a raspberry pi 3, and I am learning python. I can add in text, but it just stays in one font. I found a youtube video telling you how to add text and change the font, but that is on windows. Does anyone know how to change the font on raspberry pi 3 for pygame? 
Thank you

Comment: @L_Church I copied all of the fonts from my laptop to my raspberry pi via a pen drive, and then did what the video said and it worked!

Comment: Nice job. Can't have a font if you don't own it in the first place

Answer (score 0):

I thought that maybe I could copy the fonts across from my windows laptop across to my raspberry pi via a pen drive. I copied all of the fonts onto a pen drive and then from my pen drive to my raspberry pi, and it worked! Yey!

Answer (score 0):

While `SysFont` is an option, I prefer taking the raw .ttf file, placing it in the folder I store media in, then load it inside the game by using `pygame.Font`.